# Finding the last occurrence with multiple conditions in a lookup excel

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, lookup

Hi here is my made up data:

[image: Data & Result needed]

I am trying to get the last occurrence of a data with the two conditions (see result). I have tried to use index, match and max, but it always return the first one. Many thanks for the help. Here is my code so far:

```
=INDEX(col3,MATCH(1,(E3=colour)*(F3=code),0))
```

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Excel O365 you could utilize `XLOOKUP` with some boolean logic:

[image]

Formula in `G1`:

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(A$1:A$9=E1)*(B$1:B$9=F1),C$1:C$9,,0,-1)
```

The `-1` indicates we want to search bottom-up.

---

Without ExcelO365, you could maybe use boolean logic too:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((A$1:A$9=E1)*(B$1:B$9=F1)),C$1:C$9)
```

Or:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MAX((A$1:A$9=E1)*(B$1:B$9=F1)*ROW(A$1:A$9)))
```

and confirm through CSE.

Comment: Spot on as usual! I think for `LOOKUP` it doesn't need CSE entry as it is an array function. I remember using it without CSE.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij, I've swapped the two options around for it to make sense. Thanks for the headsup.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `AGGREGATE()` function.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$10,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($1:$10)/(($A$1:$A$10=E2)*($B$1:$B$10=F2)),1)),"")
```

[image]